# Order by subquery table

Tags: mysql, sql

I have the following query:

```
SELECT users.id, username FROM users
where exists (select 1 from topic_visits tv where users.id = tv.user_id and topic_id = 2)
order by tv.created_at;
```

I want to retrieve  all users who have visited topic 2 in ascending order (oldest visit first).

I got this error: #1054 - Unknown column 'tv.created_at' in 'order clause'.

Comment: Please provide sample data and desired results.  How is "order" defined?  How is the "topic" defined?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can change your query as shown below:

```
SELECT distinct users.id, username,tv.created_at
FROM users
join topic_visits tv ON users.id = tv.user_id and topic_id = 2
order by tv.created_at
```

Answer (score 0):

`tv` is in the sub-query, it doesn't exist at the top level.

using a join, we group by users.id so there is a unique list of users.

As the `tv.created_at` could be multiple we need to wrap it in an aggregate function, in this case MAX. Maybe MIN suites your needs better however.

```
SELECT users.id, username
FROM users
join topic_visits tv ON users.id = tv.user_id and topic_id = 2
group by users.id
order by MAX(tv.created_at);
```

Comment: `username` must be added into grouping expression (and maybe qualified with table alias).

Comment: with the assumption that users.id is a primary key, I assume you want to be lax on username in case two or more users have the same name [fiddle](https://dbfiddle.uk/?rdbms=mysql_8.0&fiddle=60f345f4341ffa8391da1c560921b38f).

Comment: I see. *with the assumption that users.id is a primary key* - 99.(9)% that this is correct, of course.